# Need some jQuery mouseover assistance

Tags: jquery

I have the following css applied to the corresponding html snippet. I would like to set it so that it changes color on mouseover. I haven't a clue how this is done correctly... can someone please enlighten me? Thanks!

CSS:

```
$('#vertical_menu li').each(function(){

    $(this).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css('color','#1c479e');
    });
});

$('#vertical_menu li').each(function(){

    $(this).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css('color','#c42026');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="vertical_menu">
    <li id="ccfl">Fort Lauderdale</li>
    <li id="ccbr">Boca Raton</li>
    <li id="ccbw">Boca (Sandalfoot)</li>
    <li id="ccbb">Boynton Beach</li>
    <li id="ccke">FL Keys</li>
    <li id="cchw">Hollywood</li>
    <li id="ccpl">Plantation</li>
    <li id="ccwb">Webcast</li>
</ul>
```

OR..... am I incorrect in removing the simple achor tags to accomplish this? I also need to add an active state when the item is clicked, and I figure since I'll do that through jQuery, I can set the rollover the same way...

Am I approaching this all wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Kenny

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished with pure CSS, no JavaScript or jQuery is needed:

```
#vertical_menu li:hover
{
    color: red;
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFXvZ/).

Comment: Ok. I have learned something new today. (I should have known that!!!)  Thanks. :o)

Comment: IE what? ;) (Thankfully, we don't have to support that one for this project)

Comment: and won't work if you want to do something more complicated than a trivial CSS change.

Comment: In web, method does not not work for IE6, IE6 does not work for method.

Comment: @Alnitak, agreed, but he's simply trying to change `color`. @Kenny, as my 3 year old would say - "Those people need to get a ***drip***!" (all 1.3% of them).

Comment: @JamesHill yeah, that's what I said... :)

Comment: I went with the simpler css method, but I do like both suggestions. Each has it's place. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for the `.each()`, and no need for separate `mouseout` functions.

Use [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to register both at once:

```
$('#vertical_menu li').hover(
    function() { // called on mouse enter
        $(this).css('color', '#1c479e');
    },
    function() { // called on mouse leave
        $(this).css('color', '#c42026');
    }
);
```

Also, note that `mouseout` doesn't actually work very well - `hover` works using pseudo-events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` emulating some MSIE functionality.

If instead you wanted the colours to only change when an item is clicked (and for the other items to revert back to their default colours) you could try this:

```
$('#vertical_menu li').click(
    function() {
        $(this)
           .css('color', '#1c479e')   // set my colour
           .siblings()                // and for my siblings
           .css('color', '#c42026');  // reset their colour
    }
);
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/fXfFN/

Comment: Oh, I like this one... this is closest to what I had in mind. Thank you.

Comment: @Kenny, this is a great answer and they way it should be done in jQuery. I would suggest that you don't make a habit of using jQuery to do simply CSS manipulation like this.

Comment: @Kenny FWIW, I agree with James - the pure CSS method is actually better for this trivial case where all you're doing is changing a colour and even works when JS is disabled.  However it's worth knowing this in case you want to do something that _can't_ be done with pure CSS.  This _is_ the right way to do it _in code_.

Comment: `.click` only takes a single callback, so you can't use that to automatically toggle things on or off.  You may need to ask a new question.

Comment: @Kenny I answered what I _think_ you were asking above.